# Detecting the Next and Previous Button Events in MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mpmovieplayercontroller

For my application I am using `MPMoviePlayerController`. The problem is that how should I detect the next and previous button events. Because in `MPMoviePlayerController` we can detect various events, but I cant find any method to detect the next and previous button events. The code I am using for detecting the other events are

```
- (void)moviePlayerPlaybackStateChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = notification.object;
MPMoviePlaybackState playbackState = moviePlayer.playbackState;
switch (playbackState) {
    case MPMoviePlaybackStateStopped:
        NSLog(@"stop");
        break;
    case MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying:
        NSLog(@"playing");
        break;
    case MPMoviePlaybackStatePaused:
        NSLog(@"paused");
        break;
    case MPMoviePlaybackStateInterrupted:
        NSLog(@"Interrupted");
        break;
    case MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward:
        NSLog(@"forward");
        break;
    case MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingBackward:
        NSLog(@"backword");
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

}

I need this as I want to play the previous and next tracks in a playlist.

Comment: u will need to add buttons externally for next and previous events

Comment: but i have seen an application on itunes which do exactly the same thing, without adding the button externally.

Answer (score 0):

There is no userInfo dictionary For MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification.